# Microsoft Access VBA Replace()

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Microsoft Access, and I'm trying to use the Replace() function.

Basically, I'm trying to change the address in a hyperlink textbox. For example, I'd like to change :
**Z:**\test_folder to **C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop**\test_folder

This is what I've got (for example):

```
Private Sub tbHyperlink_Change()
Dim Hyperlink As String
Me.tbHyperlink.Value = Hyperlink
If Left(Me.tbHyperlink.Value, 1) = "Z" Then
Replace(Hyperlink, "Z:\", "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop") As String
Me.tbHyperlink.Value = Hyperlink
Else
End Sub
```

However, this is simply not working.

Is there a simpler way to do this?
Thank you.
-Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a whole bunch of errors there, what about this?

```
Private Sub tbHyperlink_Change()
    Dim Hyperlink As String
    Hyperlink = Me.tbHyperlink.Value
    If Left(Hyperlink, 1) = "Z" Then
        Hyperlink = Replace(Hyperlink, "Z:\", "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop")
        Me.tbHyperlink.Value = Hyperlink
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, The Blue Dog.
I need to work on my VBA-fu. Still learning the basics. :)
It works well. However, I'm going to start another question, as I'm having another issue...